# OpenGL Configuration Problems. Unresolved external signals

Tags: c++, opengl

I watch "OpenGL Essentials" to learn OpenGL programming. The author writes a framework himself which contains lots of .hpp and .cpp files. To use the framework, I have to compile all files to a single Library.lib file. But there are two questions that I cannot figure it out.

1. When use the original sln provided by author, it create two lib files, one in a new created folder "Lib" and one in "Debug" folder, It also copy all hpp files in "Library" folder to a new created "include" folder. But this do not happen when I create a new VC++ project by myself. So how should i configure the VC++ project properties to make that happen.
2. When we use Glfw, we have to include glfw3.lib, and we also need to tell the exe file where to find the glfw3.dll. That's hard to understand. Because, we can compile our framework to lib file, And we also can compile it to dll file. So, Why we need both lib and dll file for GLfw? What's the difference between this two files.